# How do I specify the position of an lxterminal?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, window, lxde, lxterminal

Using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.  The terminal program is lxterminal.  In Ubuntu with gnome-terminal I can specify size and location like:

`gnome-terminal --geometry=80x30+100+100`

However in Lubuntu running

`lxterminal --geometry=80x30+100+100`

Does not position the terminal where expected. Furthermore, repeated calls to the above command result in the window being positioned in different places. The [lxterminal man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html) does not actually show position arguments

How do I specify a window position with lxterminal?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a window's position by editing `$HOME/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Back-up `lubuntu-rc.xml` as a safety measure.

Open `$HOME/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` with a plain text editor.

Scroll down to the section titled `<applications>`. You'll see a lot of text commented out.

Immediately after the last commented line, paste the following:

```
  <application class="Lxterminal" name="lxterminal">
  <position force="yes">
    <x>-0</x>
    <y>0</y>
  </position>
  </application>
```

Save `lubuntu-rc.xml` (as a plain text file).

Open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure`. There should be no error dialog window indicating parsing errors, etc.

Now, when you run lxterminal, it should open at the top right corner of your screen. Once you're sure, `lxterminal` opens as specified in the example, edit `lubuntu-rc.xml` to adjust the `x` and `y` values to suit your needs remembering to run `openbox --reconfigure` to make the changes register after saving your edits.

You can consult http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the position of a single window? I don't want every terminal window to open in the same spot, just the single terminal that I want opened on login.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to achieve that.